# my prometheus dashboard shows 0 on node_export instance

Tags: system-monitoring, prometheus, multiple-instances

I have installed prometheus on a server and node_exporter on another server

I configured my prometheus.yml to interact with the node exporter

The connection works fine but the up query shows 0 which means that the instance is not healthy.

The both servers are up and running

Any solutions on this  [image]

Comment: maybe, to try request port 9090 on server 100.25.35.55 ?

Comment: Also, look into Targets page in Prometheus. You'll at least see reason why it's considered down.